How can one ask for LDD File recommendations without the fear of being off-topic?
A bit of context
So I am busy working a diorama of the Pacific Rim Shatterdome in Lego Digital Designer, and am struggling to build the scenery normally associated with the Jaeger docks/hangars, as opposed to building the Jaegers themselves.
This question
Given my current predicament, can one ask for LDD file recommendations on the Bricks Stack Exchange, (of course the recipient taking all the risks when downloading said files)? If so, how can one go about doing so without the thread be closed for whatever reason, primarily off topic? Would a new tag be needed to ask such a question?

I'd recommend trying to focus your question on techniques for building that you're struggling with rather than "can someone build this for me" type questions - try to describe the problem you're having, examples of what you're trying to achieve, that sort of thing and you'll probably get a good answer, that helps everyone.
So for example:

I'm trying to build a Jaeger dock from Pacific Rim, but I'm struggling with getting the pipework to look good - what parts do I need?

or

How can I efficiently create greebles on my industrial hanger?

With examples of what you've tried, the sort of scale you're looking for etc.
Peter Reid's Scenery album on Flickr might be a good place to start for some further inspiration on what's possible ;) 
